# How to append to the what string of std::runtime_error

Tags: c++, exception

In the C++ library I'm writing I've extended std::runtime_error (just to have a unique type -- I don't need anything beyond a what-string).  But I sometimes want to catch the exception at the user entry point to append additional context information to the what string, and then rethrow it.  But there does not appear to be anyway to modify the what string of runtime_error.  Why is it designed that way?  Is it to avoid possible out-of-memory condition during the realloc of the internal string buffer (which would lead to a new exception)?  Or do they just want to encourage the use of nested exceptions to do this kind of thing?  (Nested exceptions seems unnecessarily cumbersome since it's all within the context of one library, but maybe I'm being wrong-headed.)  My current approach is to override the virtual what method and return my own (appendable) string:

```
#include <stdexcept>
#include <string>

class MyException : public std::runtime_error
{
    public:
        explicit MyException(const std::string& what_arg) :
                MyException(what_arg.data())
        {
        }

        explicit MyException(const char* what_arg) :
                runtime_error(""),
                what_("MyException:  ")
        {
            append(what_arg);
        }

        const char* what() const noexcept
        {
            return what_.data();
        }

        void append(const char* msg)
        {
            what_.append(msg);
        }

        void append(const std::string& msg)
        {
            what_.append(msg);
        }

    private:
        // As near as I can tell, there is no way to modify the what arg
        // of runtime_error, so I don't use it and make make my own what
        // arg here.
        //
        std::string what_;
};
```

So is this approach evil?  Is there a better way?

Comment: There is no way to modify a standard exception's `what()` string. As you have already discovered, you can make a derived class that exposes the ability to modify its own `string` variable however you want, and then override `what()` to return that `string`. Otherwise, you will just have to catch an exception and throw a new exception that contains a copy of the original exception's `what()` string and whatever amendments you want to add to it.

Comment: I also suggest you use a regular  array large enough to hold your messages instead of `std::string`.  There is a potential that `std::string` will throw an exception itself.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie:  I commonly want to include in the message a string input by the user that caused the trouble.  To do what you suggest, I'd probably start by declaring a very large array, and then add code to truncate the user string down to a size that would fit in case it's still too large.  My thinking is that the only reason std::string might throw is for out-of-memory condition.  But in that case, I think the exception from alloc would be enough to give the programmer a clue.  No?

Comment: I would not throw exceptions at all from user-input.  Exceptions should be used for *exceptional* cases. I generally do not consider malformed user-input to be exceptional and would try to report that some other way. (`std::runtime_error` messages are probably not what you'd want to report to the user anyway.) (Since you're writing a library, maybe your definition of "user" is the developer consuming the library.  If so, then okay.)

Comment: @MatthewBusche The goal is to have as few items that  can `throw`.  A `std::string` can throw on "bad usage", i.e. out of bounds accesses, not just on construction.  So IMO better to have a large array, and truncate long messages that do not fit into the array.  I know it is a compromise, but sometimes you just need to do old-school stuff.

Comment: @jamesdlin:  Yes, sorry for the confusion.  My users are programmers that (hopefully) will use my library.